# Cannot connect to an instance of SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to connect to a SQL Server 2008 server instance via NHibernate using C#. I am unable to do so.

I have been successful in connecting to to the same instance via Hibernate using java. So i am kinda sure that there is nothing wrong with my SQL Server 2008 configuration settings. I have also managed to connect to SQL Server 2008 Express.

Here is the hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
  <session-factory>

    <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver</property>
    <property name="connection.connection_string">server=(local)\SUNIL,3067;Initial Catalog=NHibernate101;User ID=sunil;Password=mypassword;</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2008Dialect</property>
    <property name="cache.use_query_cache">false</property>
    <property name="adonet.batch_size">100</property>
    <property name="proxyfactory.factory_class">NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle</property>
    <mapping assembly="Infrastructure" />
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Here is the error message:

> Test method
>   NHibernate101.Tests.RepositoriesTest.CanCreatePost threw exception: 
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:
>   Login failed for user 'sunil'.

Here is the stack trace:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection)
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior
>   runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler,
>   SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet
>   bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj)
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean
>   enlistOK)
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo
>   serverInfo, String newPassword,
>   Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout,
>   TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnection
>   owningObject)
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo
>   serverInfo, String newPassword,
>   Boolean redirectedUserInstance,
>   SqlConnection owningObject,
>   SqlConnectionString connectionOptions,
>   TimeoutTimer timeout)
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection
>   owningObject, TimeoutTimer timeout,
>   SqlConnectionString connectionOptions,
>   String newPassword, Boolean
>   redirectedUserInstance)
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
>   identity, SqlConnectionString
>   connectionOptions, Object
>   providerInfo, String newPassword,
>   SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean
>   redirectedUserInstance)
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection
>   owningConnection)
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, DbConnectionPool
>   pool, DbConnectionOptions options)
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection
>   owningObject)
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection
>   owningObject)
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject)
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection)
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory
>   connectionFactory)
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
>   NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider.GetConnection()
>   NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.Prepare()
>   NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaMetadataUpdater.GetReservedWords(Dialect
>   dialect, IConnectionHelper
>   connectionHelper)
>   NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaMetadataUpdater.Update(ISessionFactory
>   sessionFactory)
>   NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryImpl..ctor(Configuration
>   cfg, IMapping mapping, Settings
>   settings, EventListeners listeners)
>   NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.BuildSessionFactory()
>   Core.Domain.Repositories.NHibernateHelper.get_SessionFactory()
>   in
>   D:\dotnet\tutorials\NHibernate101\Core\Domain\Repositories\NHibernateHelper.cs:
>   line 22
>   Core.Domain.Repositories.NHibernateHelper.OpenSession()
>   in
>   D:\dotnet\tutorials\NHibernate101\Core\Domain\Repositories\NHibernateHelper.cs:
>   line 30
>   Core.Domain.Repositories.CategoryRepository.Core.IRepository.Save(Category
>   entity) in
>   D:\dotnet\tutorials\NHibernate101\Core\Domain\Repositories\CategoryRepository.cs:
>   line 17
>   NHibernate101.Tests.RepositoriesTest.CanCreatePost()
>   in
>   D:\DOTNet\NHibernate101\NHibernate101.Tests\RepositoriesTest.cs:
>   line 69

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message seems pretty obvious:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:
>   **Login failed for user 'sunil'**.

That would indicate that the user specified in the connection string

- has no permission to even connect to the server
- has no permission to connect to the database specified in the connection string
- a wrong password has been specified in the connection string

So I would try to fix your connection string to make sure you can log in:

```
server=(local)\SUNIL,3067;Initial Catalog=NHibernate101;
   User ID=sunil;Password=mypassword;
```

- is your SQL Server instance really called `SUNIL` and resides on your local machine?
- does your SQL Server really use port 3067 ? (this is **not** the default)
- is your database really called `NHibernate101` ?
- does a login called `sunil` exist on that server?
- is that login's password really `mypassword`?
- is that user not "blocked" or locked out for some reason?
- does a user for `sunil` exist in `NHibernate101` ?

Can you connect to **that** server, **that** database, with exactly **that** login and password, from SQL Server Management Studio??

Comment: Hey marc, yes here is the output from the portqry.exe Querying target system called:
 172.17.1.243 ( this is my local machine )
Attempting to resolve IP address to a name...
IP address resolved to miles243
querying...
UDP port 1434 (ms-sql-m service): LISTENING or FILTERED
Sending SQL Server query to UDP port 1434...
Server's response:
ServerName MILES243
InstanceName SQLEXPRESS
IsClustered No
Version 10.0.2531.0
tcp 1433
ServerName MILES243
InstanceName SUNIL
IsClustered No
Version 10.0.1600.22
tcp 3067
i am able to connect to the instance using hibernate with JAVA using the same parameters.

Comment: Yup it is working now. there was no access on the Database for user Sunil. Thanks